# In VIM, How to wrap all English words with space when save file?

Tags: vim

There are some words in vim like this:

```
你好hello
你好hello你好
hello你好
你好hi-hello你好
hi_hello你好
```

I want to automatically separate English words from Chinese words when saving the file with one space. The final format like this:

```
你好 hello 
你好 hello 你好
hello 你好
你好 hi-hello 你好
hi_hello 你好
```

I tried to use this command without success：`:%s/\(\w\+[_-]*\w*\)/ \1 /g`

With this command, there are two things that can't be done:

1. Lines beginning with English words should not have spaces at the beginning
2. Repeat commands should not repeat spaces

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
:%s/[^\x00-\xff]\zs\ze\w\|\w\zs\ze[^\x00-\xff]/ /g
```

#### Explanation

- `[^\x00-\xff]` matches any chinese character
- `\zs` marks the beggining of the actual match
- `\ze` marks the end of the actual match
- `\w` is any word character

You will note that the `\zs` and `\ze` are next to each-other, which effectively means that the **actual match is nothing**, more precisely, the *nothing* between a latin character, and a Chinese character.

Then, It's just a matter of replacing this "nothing" by a space

Comment: I try this on `配置go文件tab显示方式：不填充tab但tab显示为4个空格的长度`, it can't work rightly, result is `配置 go 文件 tab 显示方式：不填充 tab 但tab 显示为 4个空格的长度`  , the `但tab` and `4个` is incorrect

Comment: Good catch, That's something I hadn't think about! I just corrected my solution

Comment: It is working well, thank you very much! Would you please explain how it works?